# NSURL from string not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

Wrote a method to extract zip files in a temp folder and have made such that all the method in class are initiated with NSURL than path but when tried to change path to NSURL it returns null.

```
//handles all ZIP Extraction
-(NSURL*)handleZIPExtractionAtDestination:(NSURL*)destinationURL
{
    NSString *destPath=[[destinationURL path]
                     stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                        [[[_archiveURL lastPathComponent] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]
                         firstObject]];
    
    BOOL result=[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:[_archiveURL path] toDestination:destPath];
    
    if(!result)
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't extract the Files.");
        return nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",destPath);
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:destPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
  
    return url;
}
```

Result:

> destPath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/43DB7D13-9999-4231-B8AB-885CF8757931/tmp/715F6E97-968B-4FD9-A517-D9C2320A85A3-3213-0000043B8B4AFD91/900156_d378ef9fe1 2
>
> url=null

destPath uses `NSTemporaryDirectory` with `globallyUniqueString` from `NSProcessInfo`

Comment: There's no price for using the smallest number of lines of code. Use some intermediate variables so you have a chance of checking where your code goes wrong. And your code handles file extensions wrong.

Comment: Look through the documentation which methods for handling file paths there are, and use them. For example initFileURLWithPath, not URLWithString.

Comment: thanks man. what do you mean by code handles file extensions wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

Result is null because your `destPath` variable holds relative url path not complete url.for `NSURL` you need complete path like `http://web.com/you/file/path.html`
if you want local path then it should be something like `file:///path/to/your/file.html`

Comment: just append `file:///` before your destPath variable then it should work